# How to efficiently align vertices in VBO for indexed rendeing?

Tags: opengl, vbo

I have a VBO of 1 050 625 vertices representing a height map. I draw the mesh with GL_TRIANGLE_STRIPS by frustum-culled chunks of 32*32 cells with indexed rendering.

Should I care about how my vertices are aligned in the VBO in terms of performance? I mean is there any information about how distance between different elements affects performance, like: [100,101,102] or [10,1017,2078]?

Comment: Do you mean whether a group or triangles in terms of their position are far apart. Versus having closer triangles packed near each other. Whether that will have an effect on performance?

Comment: No, I mean distance in VBO between different elements of a single triangle

Answer (score 1):

Distance between indices affects the memory positions to be read from. The affection is related to cached memory. If the position is not in the current cache it must be read from main memory.

 At least theorically. In practice, it depends on hardware and driver implementantion. Cache size and bus speed have influence.

As a point to start from, anything with size below a few MB should be the quickest solution.

Anyhow, when performance is a matter, the true way of knowing about it is benchmarking different options, in different hardware if possible.

Comment: I thought it would be wise to ask first, before I'll start a huge refactoring just to check the difference